# Is it possible to assign a foreign key in a one to one relationship in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have these classes.

```
public class Foo
{
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public string BarName { get; set; }

  public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Fox
{
  public int FoxId { get; set; }
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public string FoxName { get; set; }

  public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to identify what `key` will be used as a foreign key? Say, in `Bar` class I would like to assign the `FooId` as the foreign key to `Foo` class and it goes the same to `Fox`, assign `BarId` as the FK to `Bar`.

1. With the use of fluent api. It automatically assign the primary key as the foreign key. Is there a way to override it?
2. Also, I would like to ask if this design is good/bad. Is this a reasonable design? Or should I just create one class for them?

Please let me know your thoughts.

**EDIT**

As much as possible, I don't want to use data annotations in my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one-to-one relationship your primary key should also be a foreign key. For instance in class `Bar` `FooId` should be both primary key and foreign key. See this link for explanation: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Yes. But Im just wondering, is there a way to override that behavior? Say assign another property as foreign key?

Comment: You can assign another property as a foreign key, but then its not true OneToOne, because foreign key also being a primary key doesn't allow more records from child table to reference the parent table. Primary key is what makes that constraint. If you don't want to do that way you wont have one to one constraint...

Comment: Aahh. Now it makes sense. In a 1:1 relationship, my primary key is also the foreign key so that it does not allow any duplicated records? Is that what you are saying? Please let me know if I got it right.

Comment: Well it depends on how you use them, if you always need all data (FooName, BarName, FoxName) then put them in the same table. But if you often need just FooName and no need to fetch other stuff, then one to one approach is good.

Comment: Thank you so much. You really helped me a lot. I'll pay it forward :)